# Despite of printSchema() generating output for my spark df , .show() and .count() doesn't work? Why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm currently using jupyter hub to run PySpark jobs through dataproc cluster. When i run `df.printSchema()`, it returns the schema of the dataframe whereas when i run `df.show(10)` or `df.count()`, it executes for unlimited time and doesn't generate the output. Why? and how do i check if the df is being created?

Comment: printSchema is not a Spark action so the dataframe is not evaluated, unlike with show and count. Check the monitoring for your environment to diagnose. Most likely OOM.

Comment: There are a lot of factors like machine type, size of data, underlying data source (is it a table or a view) etc that could affect the performance of your spark job. Also although count does not take much memory, it depends on what transformations and operations you are executing on your data frame before you call count. Could you update your question with this information so that I can help you better?Printing the schema of a dataFrame does not operate on contents of a data frame, like show() or other functions do.